# Failed to execute CommandLineRunner - Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, command

I tried to add insert data in to table student using command runner on spring boot project, I get "Failed to execute CommandLineRunner " error
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrELv.png]

Adding those line of code it cause error,

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-07-11 06:26:12.993 ERROR 197537 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.example.demo.student.Student; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.example.demo.student.Student
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at jdk.proxy6/jdk.proxy6.$Proxy115.saveAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.example.demo.student.StudentConfig.lambda$0(StudentConfig.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.example.demo.student.Student
        at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.instantiate(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:705) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.instantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5295) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1643) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:172) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:829) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:816) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at jdk.proxy6/jdk.proxy6.$Proxy113.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:669) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:700) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        ... 17 common frames omitted

2022-07-11 06:26:13.002  INFO 197537 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-07-11 06:26:13.002  INFO 197537 --- [  restartedMain] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
Hibernate:

    drop table if exists student cascade
Hibernate:

    drop sequence if exists student_sequence

2022-07-11 06:26:13.051  INFO 197537 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-3 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-07-11 06:26:13.056  INFO 197537 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-3 - Shutdown completed.
```

After commenting the code it's works properly.

Comment: Please post code as actual code and format logs and stacktraces as code as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Provide empty constructor with no args in your Student entity**
and make sure **You have given right mappings from your entity using @Column(name="columnNameInDatabaseTable")** to the columns of table in database
Your error says **You have not provided the Empty constructor in your Student Entity** -> "org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No default constructor for entity: : com.example.demo.student.Student; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity: : com.example.demo.student.Student"

Why do we need an empty constructor in Entity?
An empty constructor is needed to create a new instance via reflection by your persistence framework. If you don't provide any additional constructors with arguments for the class, you don't need to provide an empty constructor because you get one per default.